# How Does Trapezoidal BLDC Have Constant Toruqe

Tags: brushless-dc-motor

I'm trying to understand how a BLDC with trapezoidal back EMF can have constant torque when driven by a 6-step commutation as [some literature](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/sprabq6/sprabq6.pdf?ts=1597933303808&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fsolution%252Fdc-input-bldc-motor-drive) suggests.

Let's consider the case of a single winding pair per phase. In this case, each commutation drives the motor through 60 electrical and mechanical degrees. This 60 degrees takes the rotor-to-stator magnetic field angle from 60 to 120.

I would expect that peak torque is achieved in the middle of each commutation at exactly 90 degrees, and would expect that the resulting torque profile would be a triangular wave rather than flat.

[image]

**Edit:**
To clarify, I understand the source of the torque ripple referred to by the article and am not asking about that. I think the 10 seconds of video starting here explains my question the best: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gNpoTPzEkco&t=8m20s: "However, in BLDC motors we never achieve 90 degrees with 6-step commutation". If that's true then how do we in theory achieve constant torque?

[image]

Comment: Constant voltage = constant current = constant torque, I believe. But I see where you are coming from with proximity to the poles. I never did understand how a brushed or brushless DC motor was said to have no torque ripple.

Comment: See figure 4 . It is above 2/3 peak due to pole overlap of stator so more like rectified sine from 70 to 100%

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 The article jumps abruptly from talking about trapezoid bemf to sinusoidal.

Comment: @DKNguyen yes the winding variations are better for losses with sine torque

Comment: I think OP is trying to ask how a trapezoidal bemf motor could have no torque ripple, even if only in theory, as the article suggests. Article does state real motors do have ripple.

Comment: stator windings make the difference and motor types trapezoidal for BLDC and sine for PMSM

Comment: I've further clarified my question in the edit. Hopefully that helps. I'm not asking about torque ripple but rather the fluctuation of the rotor and stator angle between 60 and 120 degrees.

Comment: A BLDC optimised machine driven via a trapizoidal control will produce higher torque that a BLAC optimised machine (all other things equal) but will exhibit higher torque ripple. Not only due to the commutation points but also the cogging torque variations

Comment: @JonRB are you sure that is correct? I thought BLAC with sinusoidal drive gave higher torque density, as with a BLDC you always have 1/3 of your motor structure unable to contribute torque? It's been a while since I looked into all this though.

Comment: I know PMSM is sine DC source and BLAC is the AC source both sine

Comment: @Otus , you're probably confusing some concepts. The purely BLDC motor is never intended to reach the constant torque. Although the PMSM does. The thing is that they are really similar, differing basically on its magnetic field orientation inside the magnets itself and the windings. BLDC has trapezoidal wave and some techniques can achieve a good efficiency, but there's always a torque ripple. The PMSM is more likely to get no torque ripple, because it's driving method goes towards it.